# Activex object making site as untrusted for ie

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex, trusted-sites

I am testing one plugin availabilty using ActiveX object (new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.LWAPlugin15.8.InProcComponentFx") in javascript. But in IE browser it is not giving correct result. if i add my site (localhost or ip) as a trusted site then it is giving correct result. But client don't know this settings. Now my question is How to make my site as a trusted site for IE?

Comment: You can't, user decides which page to trust, not an author of any web page.

Comment: Tools>Internet Options>Security tab, click "Reset all zones to default"... quite often users (or developers) will try to tweak security zone setting in the blind hope of getting something to work.

Comment: If i use any https (trusted certificate) IE will accept or not?